# How to test if callbacks are called as expected in the async module?

Tags: node.js, asynchronous, mocha.js, sinon, chai

In the code below, two functions are run at the same time with the help of the async module.  Once a result is obtained for both functions, the final function dosomething3() is called.  How would I test if the proper callbacks are called?

```
async.parallel([
    function(cb) {
        doSomething1(function(err, result) {
            if (err) return cb(err);    // WANT TO TEST
            cb(null, result);    //WANT TO TEST
        });
    },

    function(cb) {
        doSomething2(function(err, result) {
            if (err) return cb(err);    // WANT TO TEST
            cb(null, result);    //WANT TO TEST
        });
    }

], function(err, data) {
    if (err) return handleError(err);    //WANT TO TEST
    var result1 = data[0];
    var result2 = data[1];

    dosomething3(result1, result2, function(err) {
        if (err) return handleError(err);
        process.exit(0);
    })
});
```

Comment: How about using console.log `if(err){console.log('doSomething1 error', err); return cb(err);   }` And so on in each callback

Comment: yes, use console.log or run your code with an IDE which manage breakpoints.

Comment: Do you want to debug callbacks calls or to make sure that all the callbacks were called without errors?

Comment: I want to use mocha and sinon to write unit tests for the callbacks.

Comment: @nomad see my answer, hope you understand the idea. See more info [here](http://sinonjs.org/docs/#spies)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to write unit tests, you have to write mocks for functions doSomething1, doSomething2, dosomething3, handleError. So, depending on test case, you will be able to set (or not to set) errors from these function.

for example, mock for doSomething1() will look like this (**it's just idea, sinon provides tools for testing function calls. see [here](http://sinonjs.org/docs/#spies)**):

```
// global variables that are used to controll data passed in callback of doSomething1()
var doSomething1Error = null,
    doSomething1result = [],
    doSomething1CallCount = 0;
// the mock 
function doSomething1(cb) {
  doSomething1CallCount++;
  cb(doSomething1Error, doSomething1result);
}
```

and then, your test cases will look like this

```
describe('doSomething1 ', function() {
  beforeEach(function(done) {
    // reset global vars used by mock
    doSomething1Error = null;
    doSomething1result = [];
    doSomething1CallCount = 0;
  });

  it('is called once with error', function() {
    doSomething1Error = 'User does not exist';
    // call you code under test (async.parallel([.....]))

    // check that doSomething1CallCount == 1
    // check that mock for handleError was called with 'User does not exist' error
  });
```

})